# How to track marketing efforts for iPhone apps on the App Store?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Is there a way to track marketing campaigns in the app store to find out what works and what doesn't, so you can determine which marketing techniques are actually working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sign yourself up as a referrer (or seven), so that you can see which links result in the most sales

http://losingfight.com/blog/2010/04/09/tracking-iphone-ads-to-app-sales/

Comment: Is it possible by Google Analytics or firebase dynamic links?