# Tracking iOS installs from multiple marketing sources

Tags: iphone, ios, ads

Use Case: I plan on marketing iOS apps that I own & operate. I plan on marketing these apps on FaceBook and Google. I want to understand my funnel conversion by source. Meaning what is the install rate on FaceBook v. Google from start to finish.

Outside of the app economy I would simply pass a parameter in the URL to indicate source and the web application would suck it in. If I want to use an iTunes redirect URL how would I tracking which installs came from which source?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to track marketing efforts for iPhone apps on the App Store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526723/how-to-track-marketing-efforts-for-iphone-apps-on-the-app-store)

Comment: Even now, such a function is not prepared, right?

Answer (score 7):

If it's a paid app, you can use the iTunes LinkShare affiliate program:

[How to track marketing efforts for iPhone apps on the App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526723/how-to-track-marketing-efforts-for-iphone-apps-on-the-app-store)

http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-measure-app-download-conversion-in-iTunes-appstore

If it's not a paid app, you're out of luck without a heavy 3rd-party tracking system tracking click origin, and matching that to your internal app install ID process. Painful.

Answer (score 5):

Since the introduction of [App Analytics](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-analytics/) (introduced [WWDC 2015](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-303/)) it is possible to track campaigns through the App Store.

From the [docs](http://help.apple.com/itc/appanalytics/#/itc201c43c63):

> Campaigns are custom App Store links you can use in your marketing material, websites, or advertising.
>
> To generate a campaign link:
>
> 1. Go to the Campaigns pane.
> 2. Choose your app.
> 3. Enter a campaign ID that’s up to 40 alphanumeric characters long, which can be a version of the name of your campaign.
> 4. Copy the campaign link that’s generated for you

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no way to do this.  The analytics data Apple provides via iTunes connect is really pretty weak.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If there is a free tool but Adjust is what you are looking for.

- Implement SDK to the project
- Generate a custom URL which redirects user to the Appstore
- User opens the app and SDK sends data which tells It comes from the campaign URL.

For more info you can check below links.;

https://www.adjust.com

https://docs.adjust.com/en/tracker-generation/

Comment: What about google analytics and Firebase dynamic link? Will it be achievable?